# MySQL error replacing multiple statements

Tags: mysql, sql

My interest is to replace the double quotes (") with single quote ('), and the backslash () with the slash (/). To do this I execute the following statement and it works:

```
UPDATE attrfireport_v2_core SET 
 STR_COMMENTS = REPLACE(REPLACE(STR_COMMENTS, '"', '\''), '\\', '/') 
 WHERE (STR_COMMENTS LIKE '%"%' OR STR_COMMENTS LIKE '%\\\%');
```

But if I run it as a set of statements fails:

```
UPDATE attrfireport_v2_core SET 
 STR_COMMENTS = REPLACE(REPLACE(STR_COMMENTS, '"', '\''), '\\', '/') 
 WHERE (STR_COMMENTS LIKE '%"%' OR STR_COMMENTS LIKE '%\\\%');
UPDATE attrfireport_v2_core SET 
 group_info_gral_str_equio_acce = 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(group_info_gral_str_equio_acce, '"', '\''), '\\', '/') 
 WHERE group_info_gral_str_equio_acce LIKE '%"%' 
   OR group_info_gral_str_equio_acce LIKE '%\\\%';
```

This is the error message:

> Code: 1064 SQL State: 42000 --- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE odk_prod.attrfireport_v2_group_outdoor_photo_rep SET str_ground_type_oth ' at line 2

I am using this site to corroborate my syntax: https://es.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Comment: What happens when you execute just the 2nd command?

Comment: Hi, Dan. The command is executed successfully.

Comment: Well I've learned on the http://sqlfiddle.com/ site, that some commands seems to fail in such simulations. In those cases I'm using a local testdatabase to check such queries with some testdata...

Comment: Thank you, Myonara, but not in this case. The error is also obtained by executing the command with MySQL Workbench.